# Unable to build signed apk

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, signed, signed-apk

When I want to generate a signed apk I get an IDE error:

```
Got negative length for block
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Got negative length for block
at com.intellij.credentialStore.kdbx.HashedBlockInputStream.load(HashedBlockInputStream.java:129)
at com.intellij.credentialStore.kdbx.HashedBlockInputStream.get(HashedBlockInputStream.java:100)
at com.intellij.credentialStore.kdbx.HashedBlockInputStream.read(HashedBlockInputStream.java:66)
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(InflaterInputStream.java:238)
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.read(GZIPInputStream.java:117)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityScanner.skipString(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:518)
at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:946)
at com.intellij.util.JdomKt.loadDocument(jdom.kt:82)
at com.intellij.util.JdomKt.loadElement(jdom.kt:77)
at com.intellij.credentialStore.kdbx.KdbxKt.load(kdbx.kt:89)
at com.intellij.credentialStore.kdbx.KdbxKt.access$load(kdbx.kt:1)
at com.intellij.credentialStore.kdbx.KdbxStreamFormat.load(kdbx.kt:57)
at com.intellij.credentialStore.kdbx.KdbxKt.loadKdbx(kdbx.kt:36)
at com.intellij.credentialStore.KeePassCredentialStore.<init>(KeePassCredentialStore.kt:82)
at com.intellij.credentialStore.KeePassCredentialStore.<init>(KeePassCredentialStore.kt:44)
at com.intellij.ide.passwordSafe.impl.PasswordSafeImplKt.computeProvider(PasswordSafeImpl.kt:38)
at com.intellij.ide.passwordSafe.impl.PasswordSafeImpl.<init>(PasswordSafeImpl.kt:46)
at com.intellij.ide.passwordSafe.impl.PasswordSafeImpl.<init>(PasswordSafeImpl.kt)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.picocontainer.defaults.InstantiatingComponentAdapter.newInstance(InstantiatingComponentAdapter.java:193)
at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.doGetComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:103)
at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.instantiateGuarded(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:80)
at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:63)
at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ServiceManagerImpl$MyComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ServiceManagerImpl.java:228)
at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:239)
at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:206)
at com.intellij.openapi.components.ServiceManager.doGetService(ServiceManager.java:48)
at com.intellij.openapi.components.ServiceManager.getService(ServiceManager.java:38)
at com.intellij.ide.passwordSafe.PasswordSafe.getInstance(PasswordSafe.java:28)
at org.jetbrains.android.exportSignedPackage.KeystoreStep.<init>(KeystoreStep.java:71)
at org.jetbrains.android.exportSignedPackage.ExportSignedPackageWizard.<init>(ExportSignedPackageWizard.java:110)
at org.jetbrains.android.actions.GenerateSignedApkAction.actionPerformed(GenerateSignedApkAction.java:74)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil$1.run(ActionUtil.java:215)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:232)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:309)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:929)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:136)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:299)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$fireActionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:116)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:86)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.lambda$submitTransaction$1(TransactionGuardImpl.java:109)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:118)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuard.submitTransaction(TransactionGuard.java:122)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:116)
at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:513)
at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.access$300(BegMenuItemUI.java:45)
at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:533)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6541)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6306)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4897)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4719)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4526)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4719)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:827)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:651)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:365)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

I can create a debug apk or run it on my phone which both works fine. I did already create signed apks but it suddenly stopped working.

Anyone with an idea what could cause the problem?

Comment: ensure your keystore file is not corrupted (i.e. get it from backup and check checksums of both).

Comment: my dialog does not even open - i press on generate signed apk - then this error occurs

Comment: It would be useful if you could provide details of the command you are using to generate the apk

Comment: im not using a command - i just go into my project in android studio - then i hover "build" which opens a dropdown menue where i press - generate signed apk - then i get that error (if you need more info pls tell me what you need and i can try to provide you with that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did is created a new keystore and wrote to the Android support, so I could reset it in the Play store.

More details here:

https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline.html
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423

Comment: I have same problem. Do you have other solutions?

Comment: No - there are no other solutions (you keystore is corrupted and it is build in a way to prevent you from building signed apk with a wrong keystore) - It takes a few days with android support but it worked fine with me  -- Just follow the guide on the pages I listed and you will be fine

Answer (score 1):

I delete this folder and worked for me:

```
C:\Users\Your userName\.AndroidStudio3.1
```